# What is the great advantage in "migrations" used by many PHP frameworks?

Tags: php, migration, laravel

Many PHP frameworks (becoming from Ruby) have the ability to use "migrations" and "seeding".

An example is [Laravel Framework](http://laravel.com) that have a [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/migrations) about that.

But I can't figure out how can it be useful.

Comment: How do you manage database changes right now? If you change the schema during development, how does that change end up in your production database?

Comment: Additionally, it'd be easier to manage and track these changes among multiple users working on your website as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's usefulness comes from the ability to manage a web applications database much more efficiently.  Managing even a small site with 10-20 database tables becomes as simple as making the migrations files, then running a command.  Saving both time on syntax typed, and making DB tables.

```
tutorials_tbl(
tutorial_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tutorial_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
tutorial_author VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
submission_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY ( tutorial_id )
);
```

becomes (laravel)

```
Schema::create('tutorials_tbl',function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('tutorial_title');
    $table->string('tutorial_author');
    $table->timestamps();
}
```

Now all I need to do to create the table is

```
php artisan migrate
```

Say I need to edit that table

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Edit migration file and migrate.
It makes developing more efficient, creates less hassle, makes it easier to deploy on different environments.  And seeding aids in that by giving you the ability to easily create database info that can be pushed to the DB just as easily.